# Windows schedule for Saturday before first Monday in month?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2019

I would like to schedule a task in Windows Server 2019 to run on the Saturday before the first Monday in each month. I fail to see any way to configure such a trigger.

Asking here just to make sure I haven't missed anything...?

I have found various approximations that I can accept (with some drawbacks), so please don't bother suggesting any approximations. I am only asking about an *exact* schedule as described. Time of day is not critical, but e.g. 11am would be good.

To clarify, here are a few examples:

For February 2021, the first Monday is on February 1. I would like the task to be triggered on Saturday January 30.

For June 2021, the first Monday is on June 7. I would like the task to be triggered on Saturday June 5.

Answer (score 2):

Schedule your job to run each saturday. Start it with some powershell that checks if the month 5 days earlier differs from the month two days later. If not, exit. See [devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/the-wonders-of-date-math-using-windows-powershell/) for the necessary functions.

```
if ( [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-5).month -eq [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(2).month ) {
  echo "This is not the right time";
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you improve your answer by providing the PowerShell the user would want to have executed?

Comment: Good idea! Solves the problem, albeit not using only the scheduler. I take it as a kind of confirmation that it cannot be done only using the trigger settings.

Comment: Don't take it as a confirmation, only a possible solution.  My knowledge of Windows is very limited, intentionally.

Comment: @spikey_richie Of course, but then I get lambasted by this community.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille how do you mean?

Comment: If someone asks for code it is "strengstens Verboten" to answer that.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Only if he specifically asks for code though. e.g if someone asks "i need a script that does this and this and this", and didn't show any effort to solve it himself. Here the solution is a script, but the OP didn't really know that this is the only way to do it, so posting a script as an answer is not a problem.